# Insert untracked entity with many-to-many using Id properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an application with both reference data and non-reference data.

The reference data doesn't change very often and so we've decided to cache it.

Because we are getting it from the cache, the reference data is not tracked when we query it.

I have a problem now where when I insert a new non-reference data entity, it tries to insert new items of reference data.

An example:

```
public class Plant {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int FamilyId { get; set; }
    public Family Family { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PlantColour> PlantColours { get; set; }
}

public class Family {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Plant> Plants { get; set; }
}

public class PlantColour {
    public int PlantId { get; set; }
    public int ColourId { get; set; }
    public Plant Plant { get; set; }
    public Colour Colour { get; set; }
}

public class Colour {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PlantColour> PlantColours { get; set; }
}
```

When that tried to insert a new Plant, the Family property set, it would try and insert a new Family. We can get around that by just setting the Foreign Key field `Plant.FamilyId = myFamily.Id;`

However, for many-to-many relationships like `Plant.PlantColours`, this doesn't work if I want to associate Colours to a Plant.

In particular, `Colours` from the context are cached, so they are not tracked.

If I create a new `Plant`, select from the cached Colours each Colour with a Name of a colour I want, how can I create the necessary `plant.PlantColours` if I don't yet have a PlantId to populate?

I want to avoid querying the database again for each record, as it'll be processing thousands.

Comment: I am using EF Core

Comment: Are you envisioning adding new colors or families during the addition of a plant?

Comment: Can't you just set the `Colour` property of each `PlantColour` in `plant.PlantColours` null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to avoid any reference to untracked objects, and use its `Id` fields instead:

```
List<Colour> selectedColours = GetSelectedColours(); // colours from cache
Family selectedFamily = GetSelectedFamily(); // family from cache

var plant = new Plant
{
    Name = "Black alder",
    FamilyId = selectedFamily.Id // Family property is null
};

plant.PlantColours = selectedColours.Select(c => new PlantColour
{
    Plant = plant,
    ColourId = c.Id // Colour property is null
}).ToList();

myDbContext.Set<Plant>.Add(plant);
await myDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: On first glance this appears to work and I realise how much I was overthinking the problem at 7pm!